# durandal router activator catch 401 exception

Tags: http, knockout.js, durandal

Where is the best place to catch unauthorized 401 when activating a route that was previously authorized. This happens when for instance the authorization token is no longer valid, if the user tries to activate the route, there will be 401 error. The exception in Durandal is thrown at the activateItem Level, No idea though how to define a global handler for it.

Note. mapUnknownRoutes is of no use in this scenario

Comment: What would throw a 401?  If you are in production you should never get a 401 unless you are running in debug mode if you are using weyland or grunt or any build tools.

Comment: Web API in .NET for example would throw 401 if you're no longer authorized to call an api.

Comment: Sure but Durandal's router wouldn't make a call to the API.  You would be using jQuery or something to make the call where you would handle the fail scenario.  I can post an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You catch the call from wherever you are making a call to your API from.  If you are making the call with jQuery would you handle the AJAX call's failure with the `fail` method -

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { start: start, end: end },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#myElement').append(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status === '401') {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

This gives you the status code, I can't remember if it is in string or int format though so that's pseudo code obviously

Comment: The call is made when the activator is trying to activate the route. I agree with you, the router's job is done the moment it detects the route is valid. That's why i'm trying to find a global handler when an activation of a module fails because of 401.

Comment: You can always return a promise to the router which will defer activation being complete until the promise is resolved.  If the module fails to load and you don't want to handle the failure with your call I guess you could try using a global failure handler like require.js provides but I am not sure it is the right use case - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#requirejsonerror

Comment: That would require to specifically handle the failure in each module i support authorization for. Was more looking to hook to the router somewhere, to provide a global handling. The ideal place i thought was in activeItem for the activator attached to the router. I don't have a hook for that though. There is also guardRoute but the exception happens after.

Comment: Seems like a poor separation of concerns - why not use a service and handle the failure at the service level instead of trying to catch it within the router?